# Java: Understanding Type Erasure with Generic Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, generics, generic-collections

I was wondering whether I understand the following Java issue correctly. Given a generic collection, if I do

```
public class HashTable<V extends Comparable<V>> implements HashTableInterface<V> {
    private V[] array;

    public HashTable() {
        this.array = (V[]) new Object[10];
    }
}
```

the code breaks, throwing an exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: *[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;*

However, if I change `this.array = (V[]) new Object[10];` to `this.array = (V[]) new Comparable[10];` then it works.

The way I understand it is that upon compilation the resulting bytecode will not have any generic references as they are replaced by Java's type erasure.

`this.array = (V[]) new Object[10];` breaks because the line will implicitly be replaced by `this.array = (Comparable[]) new Object[10];` which will then result in a cast exception as Object does not extend Comparable. It is resolved by changing it to an array of Comparables.

Is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: `Object` doesn't extends `Comparable` so it cannot be cast to `V`

Comment: That's pretty much how it works.

Comment: It seems to me that it has nothing to do with array in fact.  Even you have a single object reference, it is the same.  Because you have <V extends Comparable<V>>, after type erasure, V will be replaced by Comparable<V> (instead of Object), which caused the issue you faced

Comment: I agree Adrian. Just wanted to use the example I had at hand for explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The type variable is erased to the erasure of its *left most* bound. So `V` is erased to `|Comparable<V>| = Comparable`. If you changed the bound to `Object & Comparable<V>` the erasure would become `|Object| = Object` and `(V[]) new Object[10]` would work also.