# Object array not getting cast to a generic type

Tags: java, generics, casting

I intend to create a simple Dictionary ADT using a linked list. I have got little problem with the getKeys() method, here is my code:

```
@Override
public K[] getKeys() 
{
    if(head==null)
    return null;
    else
    {
        Vector<K> v = new Vector();
        ListNode<K,V> temp= head;
        while(temp!=null)
        {
            v.add(temp.key);
            temp=temp.next;
        }
        //K keys[] = new O[v.size()];

        return (K[])v.toArray();//run time error
    }
}
```

I am having the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;
    at Dictionary.ListDictionary.getKeys(ListDictionary.java:17)
    at Dictionary.DictionaryDriver.test(DictionaryDriver.java:83)
    at Dictionary.DictionaryDriver.main(DictionaryDriver.java:107)
Java Result: 1
```

Here is the interface i am trying to implement:

```
public interface DictionaryInterface <K extends Comparable<K>, V>
{
    public void insert(K key, V value);
    public V getValue(K str);
    public void remove(K key);
    public K[] getKeys();   
}
```

I understand that we cannot create an array of generics, but i never had problem with casting generic types to `Object`type.Does it have something to do with the generic type `K` extending `Comparable`? How do i work around this??

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137097/java-understanding-type-erasure-with-generic-arrays/12138773

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
return (K[])v.toArray(new Comparable[v.size()]);
```

As a side note, however, mixing generics and arrays is not the best idea.

---

To do this safely (and be able to accept types other than `Comparable`), you would need to get the type reference, so your constructor could look like this:

```
public Dictionary(Class<K> keyType) {
    this.keyType = keyType;
}
```

Later on, when instantiating that array, call:

```
return (K[]) v.toArray( Array.newInstance(keyType, v.size()) );
```

Comment: When i do this, i could eliminate the run time error from that point, but later when i create an instance of this class using `<String>` and getting the `getKeys()` i am getting this error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Comparable; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
 at Dictionary.DictionaryDriver.test(DictionaryDriver.java:83)
 at Dictionary.DictionaryDriver.main(DictionaryDriver.java:107)
Java Result: 1`

Comment: That's why mixing generics and arrays is a bad idea. You need a reference to the actual type class in order to do this safely (I'll edit my answer).

Comment: `String` implements `Comparable` then why is this failing??

Comment: i quite didn't get the edit you made to your answer.. little help?

Comment: It's failing because `Comparable[] arr = new String[0]` works fine but `String[] arr = new Comparable[0]` doesn't. You're trying to cast comparables to strings (which is your actual key type).

Comment: As for my edit: whenever you instantiate a dictionary for a given type, you must (redundantly) pass the class type as an argument and store it: `new Dictionary<String>(String.class)`. Then you can use `java.lang.reflect.Array` to create instances of arrays of that type -- which is not possible with generic types.

Comment: I re-edited to make it more explicit. Let me know if it makes sense now.