# Binary search on arrays/comparator using generics Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics, search, binary

I'm struggling to make a comparator for binary search work on an array of objects. Essentially the goal is to search a ragged array to find the first match of an item OR the closest match to provide an insert point. The method passes in an generic (this is unchangeable - as this is homework) but you can't create arrays of generic types... so, my comparator is throwing an error: "The method binarySearch(Object[], Object) in type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (Object[], E, Comparator)". Perhaps I need to cast the generic element "item"? I'm not sure. Code:

```
private Location findFirst(E item) {
    Location current;
    int closestMatchArray1;
    int closestMatchArray2;

Object[] firstItemInArray2 = new Object[numArrayInUse];
Object firstItem;

Comparator<E> comparator = new CompareElement();

for (int i - 0; i < numArrayInUse; i++) {
    firstItem = topArray[i];
    firstItemInArray2[i] = firstItem;
}

closestMatchArray1 = Arrays.binarySearch(firstItemInArray2, item, comparator);
```

Secondary, but related question. In the comparator, I am attempting to invoke the Comparable method "compareTo" to obtain a negative integer that gives an approximate location for where an item would be if it were in the array on a failed search, but again, I'm having trouble with generics, getting this error: "The method compareTo(E) is undefined for the type E". Code:

```
public class CompareElement implements Comparator<E> {
  public int compare(E firstItem, E secondItem) {
     return firstItem.compareTo(secondItem);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what error messages you get, and when/where?

Comment: Can't use List, although it would be nice. Error messages are: "The method binarySearch (Object[], Object) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (Object[], E, Comparator<E>). And "The method compareTo(E) is undefined for the type E".

Comment: @KingTriumph - Update your post with that error.

Comment: Do yo have a class named `E`?

Comment: _"The method compareTo(E) is undefined for the type E"_. `compareTo` is a method from `Comparable`. In your `CompareElement` class, `E` must be declared, i.e. `public class CompareElement<E extends Comparable> implements Comparator<E>`

Comment: @KingTriumph - Sorry, with the type parameter bound parameterized with the type you want to compare; i.e. `Comparable<YourType>`.

Comment: Thanks for this, it has helped. Essentially, I want to be able to compare _any_ type. E is generic and should stand for whatever type of object the ragged array list is filled with. That's the goal anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think you either need a `Comparator<Object>` or you need an array of `E[]`.  For the latter, I would suggest checking out these two articles:

- [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation)
- [Object array not getting cast to a generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401421/object-array-not-getting-cast-to-a-generic-type)

Above reading is encouraged.

---

### Option 1: Array.newInstance()

*assumes item is never null*

Based on what I've read in the aforementioned posts, if you know item will never be `null`, you could try something like this ...

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private Location findFirst(E item) {
    Location current;
    int closestMatchArray1;
    int closestMatchArray2;

    // Object[] firstItemInArray2 = new Object[numArrayInUse];
    // Object firstItem;

    E[] firstItemInArray2 
            = (E[]) Array.newInstance(item.getClass(), numArrayInUse); 
    E firstItem;

    Comparator<E> comparator = new CompareElement();

    for (int i = 0; i < numArrayInUse; i++) {
        firstItem = (E) topArray[i];
        firstItemInArray2[i] = firstItem;
    }

    closestMatchArray1 = Arrays.binarySearch(firstItemInArray2, item, comparator);
```

---

### Option 2: Array.newInstance()

*requires Class parameter*

If you can't guarantee the item will never be `null`, and you can't provide any special handling for `null` values, you could force the `Class<?>` parameter to be passed in, as follows...

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private Location findFirst(E item, Class<E> clazz) {
    Location current;
    int closestMatchArray1;
    int closestMatchArray2;

    // Object[] firstItemInArray2 = new Object[numArrayInUse];
    // Object firstItem;

    E[] firstItemInArray2 
            = (E[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, numArrayInUse); 
    E firstItem;

    Comparator<E> comparator = new CompareElement();

    for (int i = 0; i < numArrayInUse; i++) {
        firstItem = (E) topArray[i];
        firstItemInArray2[i] = firstItem;
    }

    closestMatchArray1 = Arrays.binarySearch(firstItemInArray2, item, comparator);
```

---

### Option 3: Object Comparator Wrapper

*ugly, but it works*

Alternatively you can create a `Comparator<Object>` to wrap your existing `Comparator<E>`, as follows (I think it's a bit of a hack, but it works consistently for me) ...

```
    private Location findFirst(E item) {
    Location current;
    int closestMatchArray1;
    int closestMatchArray2;

    Object[] firstItemInArray2 = new Object[numArrayInUse];
    Object firstItem;

    // Comparator<E> comparator = new CompareElement();
    Comparator<Object> comparator = new Comparator<Object>() {
        private final Comparator<E> delegate = new CompareElement();

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            return delegate.compare((E) o1, (E) o2);
        }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < numArrayInUse; i++) {
        firstItem = topArray[i];
        firstItemInArray2[i] = firstItem;
    }

    closestMatchArray1 = Arrays.binarySearch(firstItemInArray2, item, comparator);
```

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `Class<E>` so you may instantiate an array of `E`. (As `<E>` is dropped at runtime, E is just Object.)

```
Class<E> klazz;

E[] firstItemInArray2 = (E[])
        java.lang.reflect.Arrays.newInstance(klazz, numArraysInUse);
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not declare `<E>`. You would have to define your `CompareElement` as follows:

```
public class CompareElement<E extends Comparable> implements Comparator<E> {
    public int compare(E firstItem, E secondItem) {
        return firstItem.compareTo(secondItem);
    }
}
```

Then declare it as follows:

```
Comparator<?> comparator = new CompareElement<?>();
```

Whereas `?` should be the type you want to compare.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `E` declared? It seems like some type parameter that is declared in some enclosing class that we can't see. It seems that your `CompareElement` class is a comparator that compares elements based on their natural ordering (i.e. according to `Comparable`). If so, then `E` must have a bound that guarantees that it is able to compare to itself, `<E extends Comparable<? super E>>`. You can change that bound where `E` is declared, or, if you want to do it like other people have suggested, to have `CompareElement` be parameterized separately from the enclosing class, you would do this:

```
public class CompareElement<E extends Comparable<? super E>> implements Comparator<E> {
  public int compare(E firstItem, E secondItem) {
     return firstItem.compareTo(secondItem);
  }
}
```

Your first error is because the version of `binarySearch` you're trying to use, the one with a comparator, has restrictions on the types of the arguments. It is declared like this: `static <T> int binarySearch(T[] a, T key, Comparator<? super T> c)`. So If you have a `Comparator<E>`, then you will need an `E[]` as first parameter, whereas you have an `Object[]`. You have to think of some way to make it `E[]`.

But actually for you you're trying to do you don't need to use a comparator at all. There is a version of the `binarySearch` method that does not take a comparator, and it already compares elements using their natural ordering.